# Why am I getting node-sqlite3 SQLITE_BUSY

Tags: node.js, sqlite

I have a problem with a webserver that stores data periodically in a node-sqlite3 driven database. It will work fine a few times and then just fails with

> SQLITE_BUSY: database is locked

Sometimes all inserts are not completed to the database even when not failing, leaving only a portion of the inserts in the table.

```
setInterval(doInserts,60000);

doInserts() {
calculateData(function(data){
    if(data)
    {
        insertData(data);
    }
});
}

function insertData(data) {
var sqlite3 = require("sqlite3").verbose();

//user fs existSync to check if file exists and openSync(file,'w') to create if not

db.serialize(function(){
    var stmt = db.prepare("INSERT INTO mytable (col1,col2) values (?,?)");

    for(var i =0;i<data.length;i++)
        stmt.run(data[0],data[1]);
    stmt.finalize();
});
db.close();
}
```

Taking account I am new to both node and SQLite, I'm guessing that I am using something in the wrong way, causing multiple open threads or processes to lock up the db, but no documentation or research has gotten me any closer to a solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect you understand Node\Sqlite correctly.  I had the same problem using Sqlite3#serialize.  I ended up not using it in the end, and instead used the pattern in [chapter 7.2.2 of Mixu's Node Book.](http://book.mixu.net/node/ch7.html)  to control the flow of the db queries.  Basically you have an array of functions.  Each function has a callback that invoke the next function.

Answer (score 12):

Just chipping in what solved it for me. This was happening whenever I had a data viewer application looking at the database. Once closed, it began working again!

Comment: I'm so annoyed, but this fixed it for me as well. Haha

Comment: Silly as it looks, this is very likely to be the solution to such an annoying problem.

Comment: you just saved me a ton of pain and frustration

Answer (score 1):

SQLite database works fine with just 1 transaction a time. So, if you have several concurrent requests to your DB, sometimes you will lock database.

SQLite has some very simple mechanism for a transaction to wait until another transaction is in progress, but it's not enough.

I solved the same problem in a similar way, as @MattShirilla suggested. You either need to use a queue or control flow to avoid locks for sure.

Answer (score 0):

Queries in cycle -- bad idea at all. 
Use https://github.com/mapbox/node-sqlite3/wiki/API#databaseexecsql-callback instead

```
SQLITE_BUSY: database is locked
```

I gives this messages when database already was opened by another program.